# Testing In App Purchases on iOS with no error

Tags: ios, iphone, in-app-purchase, xcode5

This is my first app I have made in `iOS` with in app purchases. I am having difficulty testing the in app purchases. This is a reskinned game so the functions have already been integrated. I am ready to submit the game to apple but I am held up on trying to confirm the in app purchases work properly.

I have a *test user account* that I signed in with and I purchase the *in-app-purchase* with test user. It reads "purchasing" then disappears but never does the purchasing function it is suppose to??  There is no error message!? Function is suppose to buy additional coins but these coins do not show up after "purchasing".

Is this suppose to work when testing in app purchases?

```
Reachability* reachability = [Reachability reachabilityWithHostName:@"www.google.com"];
NetworkStatus internetStatus = [reachability currentReachabilityStatus];
if (internetStatus != ReachableViaWiFi && internetStatus != ReachableViaWWAN) {

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"No Internet Connection" 
                                                    message:@"You require an internet connection via WiFi or cellular network for connecting to online store" 
                                                   delegate:nil 
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss" 
                                          otherButtonTitles:nil];

    [alert show];
    [alert release];
    bErrorOnConnection = YES;
}




if ([SKPaymentQueue canMakePayments])
{
    [self requestProductData];

} else {
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"In-App Purchases are disabled" 
                                                    message:@"Please check your restrictions for In-App Purchases in Settings->General->Restrictions." 
                                                   delegate:nil 
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss" 
                                          otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
    bErrorOnConnection = YES;
}

- (IBAction) closePressed:(id) sender {
[mainGameParent GameStoreClosed];
[self.view removeFromSuperview];
```

}

```
- (IBAction) purchaseUnlock:(id) sender {

bool bPaymentInQueue = NO;
for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in [SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue].transactions) {
    if ([transaction.payment.productIdentifier isEqualToString:kPayoutUnlockProduct]) {
        bPaymentInQueue = YES;
        NSLog(@"Payment already in queue!");
        break;
    }
}
if (!bPaymentInQueue) {
    NSLog(@"Adding new payment...");
    SKPayment *payment = [SKPayment paymentWithProductIdentifier:kPayoutUnlockProduct];
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment];
}



  (IBAction) restore:(id)sender {
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions];
```

}

```
- (IBAction) moreGames:(id)sender {
SurfSlotMachineAppDelegate* del = (SurfSlotMachineAppDelegate*)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
[del dispMoreApps];
```

}

```
- (void)requestProductData {

//lblLoading.hidden = NO;
[activityIndicatorView setHidden:YES];
//[activityIndicatorView startAnimating];

SKProductsRequest *request = [[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers:[NSSet setWithObject:kPayoutUnlockProduct]];

NSLog(@"%@",kPayoutUnlockProduct);
request.delegate = self;
[request start];



- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions
{
for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in transactions)
{
    switch (transaction.transactionState)
    {
        case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:
            NSLog(@"Transaction Purchased");
            [self completeTransaction:transaction];
            break;
        case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:
            NSLog(@"Transaction Failed");
            [self failedTransaction:transaction];
            break;
        case SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored:
            NSLog(@"Transaction Restored");
            [self restoreTransaction:transaction];
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

}

Any tips on how I fix this code to work? Is it a simple fix?

Comment: would you post your - (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions up here and check what's inside?

Comment: I have added the code. Is there code I have missed to post that will help you with my question? Thanks!

Comment: and did you do the unlock/upgrade in your - (void)completeTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction ?

Comment: I have not touched the code for in app purchases. I purchased a source code and paid to have the game reskinned. I assumed the game was fully functional and I just had to reskin the graphics. I am a beginner with coding which is why I decided to reskin games as my first venture in the app world. Any further guidance you can give me so I can fix my in app purchases?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well if you haven't touch the code it will surely not work. The purchase should be able to get completed but you have to implement

```
- (void)completeTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction
```

to update what the user should get after the purchase.

Comment: I have searched my code and I do have that line in the files Mystoreobserver.h  and mystoreobserver.m  , do I need to add it in somewhere else?

Comment: No, you need to add something inside. what do you want your user to have after purchasing?

Comment: The user will buy coins/credits they win from a casino slot app to use again in app when they run out of credits.

Comment: then add coins to the user's account in the method.

Comment: that will be specific to your implementation.